# combining 2 columns using ifelse dropping a variable R

Tags: r, if-statement, multiple-columns

I am trying to combine the male and female columns I have created into one column.  I tried using some answers I found on stack, but the second sex I queried was excluded.

Build Data Frame:

```
ID <- 1:10
SPAYDT <- c("", "2011-12-01", "", "2006-05-01", "", "", "", "", "", "")
SPAYDTU <- c(1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
NEUTDT <- c("", "", "", "", "", "", "2013-03-01", "", "", "")
NEUTDTU <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(ID, SPAYDT, SPAYDTU, NEUTDT, NEUTDTU))
df
```

The goal is to have a column for sex, formated as a factor with 2 levels - Male and Female
It should say female if the SPAYDT or SPAYDTU have a value in them, and male if the NEUTDT or NEUTDTU have a value in them.
What I have tried:

- using a nested if-else statement to build one sex column
- making two columns then combining using

```
df$male <- ifelse(NEUTDT!="", "Male",
                  ifelse(NEUTDTU=1, "Male", NA))
df$female <- ifelse(SPAYDT!="", "Female",
                    ifelse(SPAYDTU==1, "Female", NA))
df$sex <- ifelse(!is.na(df$female), df$female, df$male)
```

and

```
df$sex <- ifelse(SPAYDT!="", "Female",
                 ifelse(SPAYDTU==1, "Female",
                        ifelse(NEUTDT!="", "Male",
                               ifelse(NEUTDTU=1, "Male", NA))))
```

However, no matter what I do, the sex column at the end only has one sex.  I made sure my df was attached for use of column names as variables.  I tried restarting R and running the setup code again.  I just don't know why the ifelse statement is ignoring the second sex input.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Clarifications:
In the larger dataframe I am working with I have done data clean up so that each ID only corresponds to 1 sex. Sorry about the mistake in the code.

Desired output:

```
ID <- 1:10
SPAYDT <- c("", "2011-12-01", "", "2006-05-01", "", "", "", "", "", "")
SPAYDTU <- c(1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
NEUTDT <- c("", "", "", "", "", "", "2013-03-01", "", "", "")
NEUTDTU <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA)
SEX <- c("Female", "Female", NA, "Female", NA, NA, "Male", "Male", NA, NA)
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(ID, SPAYDT, SPAYDTU, NEUTDT, NEUTDTU, SEX))
df
```

Comment: One column by definition has one value.  How do you want to handle the case where both genders are assigned?

Comment: Are you sure you have created the dataframe correctly ? I think in the last line it should be `cbind` instead of `rbind`. Also can you update your post with the expected output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are after?

```
ID <- 1:10
SPAYDT <- c("", "2011-12-01", "", "2006-05-01", "", "", "", "", "", "")
SPAYDTU <- c(1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
NEUTDT <- c("", "", "", "", "", "", "2013-03-01", "", "", "")
NEUTDTU <- c(NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
df <- data.frame(ID, SPAYDT, SPAYDTU, NEUTDT, NEUTDTU)

df %>% 
 mutate(
   sex = case_when(
      NEUTDT!="" | NEUTDTU==1 ~ "Male", 
      SPAYDT!="" | SPAYDTU==1 ~ "Female", 
      TRUE ~ NA_character_))
```

Comment: Just add an addition to your post. It is possible to use `NA` of `character` type: `NA_character_`

Comment: @slava-kohut, thanks a lot. It is good to know. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Great! I am glad it helps.

Comment: What if I wanted to use & statments instead of or statements?  Should this still work?

Comment: Of course, you need to work out the logic. In your example, you will generate all `NA` for the new variable `sex`.